# Should this question be reopened?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-closed

I stumbled on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27316233/1210260) today, which is closed as "unclear what you're asking". The question as it stands seems rather clear to me: It asks how to implement getters and setters in C and when they should be preferred over extern variables. The question could be edited to make it marginally more clear, but I think it's fine in its current form.

Comment: But it is also too broad as asking for unbounded list of reasons... Unless you clarify why it is on-topic there is generally no reason to re-open for immediate re-close between "unclear" and "too broad" (may be ok from "unclear" -> "duplicate" for example).

Comment: I've edited the question to be more clear and direct. The wording of the question body was slightly confusing when given the context of the title and the answers. Now it all matches up nicely. Voted to reopen

Comment: [tag:status-completed]